# Data Insertion And Page Redirect Not Working jQuery directly printing Else Part

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working with HTML, PHP, jQuery.

In HTML Form with input type button I am sending data to jQuery and with post I am send to PHP file and then inserting in the database, the problem in my scenario is that in JavaScript file I am just getting else part of the code, the else part is "Enter Your Details Correctly" and data is not inserted in the database, and also page redirect is not working in both success or failure of data insertion. I will really appreciate your time if you guys can help.

On different project my data is inserted in the database but page redirect not working, for page redirect I tried `window.location.href`, `window.location.replace`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    "use strict";
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var contact = $("#contact").val();
        var gender = $("input[type=radio]:checked").val();
        var msg = $("#msg").val();

        if(name ===''|| email===''|| contact===''|| gender===''|| msg==='') {
            alert("Insertion Failed Some Fields are Blank....!!");      
        }
        else {
            $.post(
                "contactsave.php",
                { name: name, email: email, contact: contact,gender:gender, msg:msg},
                function(data) {
                    if(data.message==='success')
                    {
                        window.location.replace("http://multimighty/contactthankyou.php");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Enter Your Details Correctly");
                    }
                },
                'json');
        }
    });
});


/*contactsave.php*/
<?php
    $name=$_POST['name']; 
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $contact=$_POST['contact'];
    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    $msg=$_POST['msg'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO test(name, email, phone, gender, message) VALUES ('$name','$email','$contact','$gender','$msg')";

    if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo json_encode(array("message"=>"success"));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("message"=>"failuer".$con->error));
    }
    $con->close(); 
    exit;
?>
```

I just want a simple form insertion without page refresh and after that page redirect

Comment: Please format your code and provide an description of what happens when you run it.

Comment: Thanks robinsax, when i am submitting form it shows me alert box Enter your details correctly and its not redirecting page on html file i am submitting form with input type button and id is submity

Comment: Then your next step is to `console.log(data)` before your if statement

Comment: @Bilal this would suggest that `data.message` != "success" or that it has `null` or `undefined` value. Do what @robinsax suggested.

Comment: Thanks @robinsax  for your help, insertion problem is solved but still i cant redirect my page, if someone can help me with that please.

Comment: Its bit strange page redirect working on Mozila Developer browser but its not working on Chrome and MS Edge any idea? Please